# Understanding how PHP treats references to arrays

Tags: php, arrays, pass-by-reference

In PHP 5.5.33, I want to create an array of arrays, inside a repeat loop. I have found 3 different ways of doing this, which give 3 different results. The first result is the one I want, so I have a solution. What I need is an understanding of why these three ways lead to different outcomes.

The first two examples make sense to me. The third seems to apply alien logic. In the third example, I create a new reference to a new array on each iteration, and yet the same reference is added to the output array each time. Why does $inner, in the last example, not get recreated at a new memory address each time?

```
<?php
// Inner array added after it is changed
$outer = array();
for ($ii=0; $ii<3; $ii++) {
  $inner = array("value" => 0);
  $inner["value"] = $ii;
  $outer[$ii] = $inner;
}

echo json_encode($outer);
// [{"value":0},{"value":1},{"value":2}] 
?>

<br />

<?php
// Innner array added as a copy, and then changed
$outer = array();
for ($ii=0; $ii<3; $ii++) {
  $inner = array("value" => 0);
  $outer[$ii] = $inner;
  $inner["value"] = $ii;
}

echo json_encode($outer);
// [{"value":0},{"value":0},{"value":0}] 
?>

<br />

<?php
// Inner array created, then added by reference, then changed
$outer = array();
for ($ii=0; $ii<3; $ii++) {
  $inner = array("value" => 0); // shouldn't this be different each time?
  $outer[$ii] = &$inner;
  $inner["value"] = $ii;
}

echo json_encode($outer);
// [{"value":2},{"value":2},{"value":2}]
?>
```

Answer (score 2):

It is simple - on the 3th sample you're creating the array of 3 synonyms to the variable $inner['value']. In same tame you every time change the $inner['value'] to $ii. On the end you have array of 3 pointers, which point to $inner['value'], but $inner['value'] obtained 2 - that is and the result.

And in case you are expecting that $inner = array("value" => 0); will take different place - you aren't on right way. This is equal if you empty and create the array - it is reseting the array every time.